# Adding React to a site; use of hooks/functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am very new to react and need to rebuild two Angular.js components within a .NET Content Management System (Kentico). I do not believe there is an opportunity to run a react app/component through npm so I have gone the other route and "add React to a website" (https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html). I'm using browserify with babelify to compile my app/component code for the browser.

I've made some decent progress but believe I like the flexibility functional components bring to the table where I don't find coding within a class component all that familiar. Because I'm "adding React to a site" instead of running it through npm, I BELIEVE I have no opportunity to import hooks and thus: no opportunity for useState within functional components.

Can anyone verify this for me? That indeed, "adding react to a site" precludes one from using functional components: class components are the best I can do?

I guess it boils down to: I do not believe I can import useState/useEffect when I am "adding react to a site" in a way where react and react-dom are just script references at the base of my component.

Maybe someone can verify that for me or else point out how I would capitalize on functional components/hooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks and classes freely no matter how you include them. It's not relevant. The old react docs only use classes which is confusing. Try beta docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/

Comment: With me using https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js as a script tag instead of adding it through NPM it appears there's no option to import anything from React. But when wanting to useState I was able to use React.useState. Is it accurate to say that importing hooks, etc from React is not relevant to someone adding react to a site with the script references? But that all functionality such as hooks is available in those JS reference by way of namespaces?

Comment: Yes. You cant use `import` syntax because you are importing the UMD version which does not support ESM imports. But you can still reach everything through the `React.` scope.

Comment: If you want `import` syntax you can look into instead importing the ESM module. See https://esm.sh/#docs:~:text=How%20to%20Use-,Import%20from%20URL,-import%20React%20from

Comment: Oh boy. Not knowinght difference between ESM and UMD cost me some time here. Thank you so much for taking the time to not just confirm but to offer alternatives. I really appreciate it.